# Using Json Schema with wordpress codex

Tags: codex

I have a json schema code that I need to use it for all posts

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "https://akhbarejadid.com/457881/"
  },
  "headline": "title",
  "description": "this is a test description",
  "image": "https://media.imna.ir/d/2021/07/15/4/1713968.jpg",  
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Javad"
  },  
  "publisher": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "Akhbarejadid",
    "logo": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "url": "https://akhbarejadid.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/logoakhbarejadid.png"
    }
  },
  "datePublished": "2022-03-01",
  "dateModified": "2022-03-16"
}
</script>
```

Can I use wp codes like the_title(); or the_author(); or the_content(); for this json schema?
For example :

```
"headline": "<?php the_title(); ?>",
  "description": "<?php the_excerpt(); ?>",
  "image": "https://media.imna.ir/d/2021/07/15/4/1713968.jpg",  
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "<?php the_author(); ?>"
```

Comment: Sure. You just need to create a child theme and add the code you desire there, so it doesn't get overwritten when you update your parent theme.

Comment: Use Slim SEO Schema which supports custom JSON-LD and dynamic variables https://wpslimseo.com/slim-seo-schema/